# How can I add float values together from a dictionary of mixed lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to add together values from mixed-value lists in a dictionary:

```
sampledict = {key1:[str1,float1],key2:[str2,float2], key3:[str3,float3]}

all_floats = float1+float2+float3
```

I will preface that I am fairly new to coding so I apologize for any lack of clarity.

I tried a TypeError exception to isolate the floats, but ran into errors. I tried using sum(), but it didn't like the mixed data type.

Answer (score 0):

- Each value in your dictionary is a list.
- In each list, the float you care about is the *second* element.
- So for each value in your dictionary, you want to add up the *second* element of that list

Let's do that:

```
total = sum(value[1] for value in sampledict.values())
```

Or, if you want a regular loop, initialize `total=0` before the loop, and then keep adding `value[1]` to it inside the loop:

```
total = 0
for value in sampledict.values():
    total += value[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd probably do it:

Step 1: gather all the data...

```py
my_dict = {
    'key1':["str1", 1.0112, 1],
    'key2':["str2", 2.3121, 5], 
    'key3':["str3", 1.5123, 'z']
}

# this grabs all the values using list instantiation and puts them in one list
all_values = sum([ value for key,value in my_dict.items() ], [])
```

2. Iterate over the list of items and take only the type you want

```py
# iterate over that list and select only the ones of type float (or whatever)
floats = [ value for value in all_values if type(value) == float ]
```

3. Add up the floats (or whatever)

```py
print(sum(floats))
```

Comment: You can skip one loop if you define `floats` as a generator instead of a list comprehension

Comment: Nice, I see that in your example. Does that still work in this case where it's a nested list though? Don't you end up with a list of lists?

Comment: I extract a single value from each list using `value[1]`. Your `floats` isn't a list of lists though, so you could simply skip the list comprehension and pass the generator directly to `sum`

Comment: Glad to hear!, @JosephBruen can you please mark an accepted answer?